# Hibernate: how to reverse engineer and use a Postgres serial type column?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, reverse-engineering

I have the following table in a Postgres database:

```
CREATE TABLE net.polygon
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  x numeric,
  y numeric,
  CONSTRAINT pk_polygon PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The `serial` types automatically creates a sequence that is used to create a new primary key every time a new row is inserted in this table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE net.polygon_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
```

I need to insert data into this table from a Java programme. I am using Hibernate to reverse engineer this database; the `reveng.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    [...]
    <table-filter match-name="polygon"></table-filter>

    <table name="polygon">
        <primary-key>
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">polygon_id_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </primary-key>
    </table>

</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

This generates the appropriate POJO and the following mapping for the `polygon` table:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 15, 2016 9:54:40 AM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Polygon" table="polygon" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">polygon_id_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="x" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="x" precision="131089" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="y" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="y" precision="131089" scale="0" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

In the Java code, new `Polygon` objects are created like:

```
polygon = new Polygon();
polygon.setX(someValue);
polygon.setY(anotherValue);
session.save(polygon);
```

But it produces the following exception:

> ERROR: relation "net.hibernate_sequence" does not exist

I have searched the code and could not find any reference to this `hibernate_sequence` relation. If it is a sequence, why is Hibernate trying to use it instead of the one provided in the `reveng.xml` file?

**Update**: Folks at the Hibernate IRC tell me this is an issue with Hibernate Tools, that [is not yet up to date with the latest Hibernate release](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-20446?jql=project%20%3D%20JBIDE%20AND%20component%20%3D%20hibernate%20AND%20text%20~%20%225.0%22).

Comment: This is weird. Did you try clean build your project?

Comment: Yes, but the error remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Hibernate Tools issue is not solved, sequences can be used with Eclipse Mars using this kind of mapping in the `.reveng.xml` file:

```
<table name="entity">
    <primary-key>
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator">
            <param name="optimizer">none</param>
            <param name="increment_size">1</param>
            <param name="sequence_name">entity_id_seq</param>
        </generator>
    </primary-key>
</table>
```

This `primary-block` will get inserted automatically in the `hbm.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 23, 2016 2:14:25 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1.Final -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Entity" table="entity" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idEntity" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id_entity" />
            <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator">
                <param name="optimizer">none</param>
                <param name="sequence_name">entity_id_seq</param>
                <param name="increment_size">1</param>
            </generator>
        </id> 
        [...]
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and the correct sequence will be used (`entity_id_seq` in this case). Although it requires the identification and manual set up of each sequence, this solution requires no changes to the generated classes and configuration files, it is therefore a one-time task.